# TCP threaded python server not handling signals as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tcp, python-server-pages

I am required to run a server which processes at max 3 requests at a time. My design is I have a TCP server running and will have 3 threads running to process those requests. The server will accept requests and will pass those requests to threads using corresponding queues for the locks. I have appropriate locks for the queues as well. My issue is, even though I have a signal handler to signal the threads when the main process has to exit, using a flag. I am not understanding what the error is because of which the graceful exit is not happening as expected. The output is as follows:

```
vm:~/Desktop$ python multi_threaded_queueing.py
About to kickoff
About to kickoff
Starting Thread-1
About to kickoff
Starting Thread-2
Starting Thread-3
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_threaded_queueing.py", line 94, in <module>
    conn, addr = s.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
socket.error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

The code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Queue
import threading
import time
import sys
import socket
import signal


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = None

exitFlag = 0
#signal handler for control C
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print "Control+C has been pressed"
    #setting the exit flag so that all the threads can get notified
    exitFlag = 1
    #wait till all the threads have finished processing and can gracefully exit
    #I maintain an array for each thread to set the corresponding index when
    #it has finished its processing. I and all the elements to see if its 0
    #and based on which I will exit or wait
    while 1:
        num = 0
        for ele in exitList:
            num &= ele
        if ele == 0:
            sys.exit(0)

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    #have a queue, thread ID and name for every thread.
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        process_data(self.name, self.q, self.threadID)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def process_data(threadName, q, threadID):
    #while exit flag is not set by the main thread keep processing the data
    #present in the queue.
    while not exitFlag:
        queueLock[threadID].acquire()
        if not workQueue[threadID].empty():
            data = q[threadID].get()
            queueLock[threadID].release()
            print "%s processing %s" % (threadName, data)
        else:
            queueLock[threadID].release()
        time.sleep(1)
    exitThread[threadID] = 1

threadList = ["Thread-1", "Thread-2", "Thread-3"]
nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
queueLock = []
workQueue = []
threads = []
threadID = 0
exitList = []
size = 3
request = 0
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

# Create new threads
#by default hard coding the number of threads to 3
for tName in threadList:
    workQueue.append(Queue.Queue(10))
    queueLock.append(threading.Lock())
    exitList.append(0)
    thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue)
    print "About to kickoff"
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    threadID += 1


for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
        s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
    except socket.error, msg:
        s = None
        continue
    try:
        s.bind(sa)
        s.listen(1)
    except socket.error, msg:
        s.close()
        s = None
        continue
    break
if s is None:
    print 'could not open socket'
    sys.exit(1)
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr
    request += 1
    #round robin scheduling for each thread
    thread_index = request % size
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        # Fill the queue with the request received
        queueLock[thread_index].acquire()
        for word in nameList:
            workQueue[thread_index].put(word)
        queueLock[thread_index].release()
        # Wait for queue to empty
        while not workQueue[thread_index].empty():
            pass
        conn.send(data)
    conn.close()



# Notify threads it's time to exit
exitFlag = 1
print "setting the exitFlag"
# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Comment: Have you tried to use multiprocessing (Process) instead of threads ? You probably cannot perform multiple accept calls, even though its on different threads. With the multiprocessing module you can have three processes with separate execution environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on.

1. `signal_handler(signal, frame):` isn't setting the global `exitFlag`. You need to add `global exitFlag` to the top of the function.
2. `sys.exit()` doesn't really exit - it just raises a `KeyboardInterrupt` error.
3. `socket.error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call` is good stuff, its what keeps your program from getting stuck in `conn, addr = s.accept()`. You should catch `socket.error` exceptions and use them to break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on global! Completely missed that part out! and instead of using sys.exit() I have used SystemExit(0) which seems to be working fine. Thanks for the tips.:)..